# read line from text then copy into structure

Tags: c++, file, input, io, output

So I understand the basic concept of reading a text file line by line using a while loop, now my question is how do I read each line and then put the contents of those lines into a variable that is part of a structure?

I figured out how to write my text to a file but not how to store the information from that same file so here is what I have so far but it does not seem to work:

**This works:**

```
void save(string fileName)
{
    Container *traverser = list;
    ofstream file;
    file.open(fileName);

    while (traverser != NULL){
        file << traverser->student->getFirstName() << endl;
        file << traverser->student->getLastName() << endl;
        file << traverser->student->getGrade() << endl;
        file << traverser->student->getEdu() << endl;
        traverser = traverser->next;
    }
}
```

**This doesn't:**

```
void load(string fileName)
{
    Container *traverser;
    Container* c;
    Student *s;
    string fname, lname;
    int grade;
    int edu;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(fileName);
    string line;

    while (getline(file, line)){
        file >> fname;
        file >> lname;
        file >> grade;
        file >> edu;
        s = new Student(fname, lname, grade, edu);
        c = new Container();
        c->student = s;
    }
}
```

Is it something with my syntax or am I doing it wrong all together?

The program essentially asks for the students first and last names, grade, and education then it stores that into a text file, then it is supposed to load the information from the text file back into the program (I didn't post the whole code because there is a lot).

Thanks!

Additional info: list is a linked list of Structures (students)

Comment: Is this homework? That is to say are you not able to use standard containers like `vector` or `list`?

Comment: You read a line and then you parse even more things from the file stream? Sure you do not want to parse the line with a stringstream?

Comment: You don't need getline. Use while( file >> fname >> lname >> grade >> edu )...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your data is in one line

```
while (getline(file, line)){
    istringstream lstr(line);
    lstr >> fname;
    lstr >> lname;
    lstr >> grade;
    lstr >> edu;
    s = new Student(fname, lname, grade, edu);
    c = new Container();
    c->student = s;
}
```

This could already do the job.
Edit: You might want to `#include <sstream>`